# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid issue with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am using Rails 4 and I am editing an existing application. I am getting the following error when viewing a model in active admin.

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin::Events#show`

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column trainers.event_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "trainers".* FROM "trainers"  WHERE "trainers"."even...
                                                ^
: SELECT  "trainers".* FROM "trainers"  WHERE "trainers"."event_id" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

I dont actually have or need that column so I cannot see why its being looked for. Here is my `Event` model.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one     :trainer, inverse_of: :events
 belongs_to  :training_request, inverse_of: :event

 delegate :module, to: :training_request
end
```

Iv done `rake db:migrate` and its all up to date. Can anyone see why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With rails, the association has_one and belongs_to requires the id of the "events" table inside the "trainers" table, so it can define in your trainers table which event are you referring to, so you need to add event_id column to the trainers table.

To do that you can generate a migration

```
rails g migration add_event_id_to_trainer event_id:integer
```

then  run

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Sorry noticed it was a bug from previous dev the event model was meant to be `belongs_to  :trainer, inverse_of: :events`